# Are there any evocative dictionaries?

Tags: dictionary, symbol

There are analogical dictionaries which list words and phrases related to a topic.
And there are symbolic dictionaries which explain what a thing represents.

But I have not found a dictionary that list what a thing evokes.

For example a whale evokes the sea, the giant size, the vulnerability, the rarity.
The car evokes speed, technology, noise, transportation, voyage, protection but also danger.

Where can I find a list of evocations for the most common things?

Comment: What a word evokes is very individualistic, I don't think such a dictionary would be useful. I don't agree with all of the examples you listed just in this question!

Comment: Thesaurus may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @amegnunsen it seems to be the same as an analogical dictionary - we call it that in French.

Comment: Thesaurus is made to give semantic relationships, often hierarchical, between words, as you seem to seek. There is also WordNet, otherwise.

Comment: @amegnunsen it's definitely not what I seek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are - if I understood you correctly, but I've seen only one so far, for the Russian language. It's called *Русский ассоциативный словарь* (Russian Associative Dictionary), in two volumes.

You can read more about how it was compiled in [Ufimtseva 2014](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S187704281405558X).

As for English, I've only seen *The Edinburgh Associative Thesaurus*. http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/data/dic/eat/Eat.htm

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such thing. I just did a round of gathering dictionaries over the past few months and didn't encounter anything like this.

The closest thing I have ever come across is something related to Lakoff's work on [Conceptual Metaphors](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/2p93q7nr). They have collected a compendium of meanings like this (the conceptual metaphor it evokes) for many words, but I can't seem to find it online. Perhaps [this](https://metaphor.icsi.berkeley.edu/pub/en/index.php/Category:Metaphor) is it.